# Spricht man „mit spitzer Zunge“ oder „mit scharfer Zunge“ (oder beides)?

Tags: difference, phrase, idiom

Wenn bspw. Satiriker kein Blatt vor den Mund nehmen und unverblümt schmähreden, ist ihre Zunge dann eher spitz, scharf oder beides?

- Adjektivisch scheint es auf jeden Fall sowohl [*scharfzüngig*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/scharfzuengig) als auch [*spitzzüngig*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/spitzzuengig) zu geben.
- Idiomatisch gibt es [*mit spitzer Zunge sprechen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/spitzzuengig#Bedeutungb), allerdings hat [*mit scharfer Zunge*](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22mit%20scharfer%20Zunge%22) mehr Treffer.
- Das [Ngram von „scharfe Zunge“ und „spitze Zunge“](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spitze%20Zunge%2Cscharfe%20Zunge&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=) ist relativ ausgewogen (allerdings nicht so sehr wie [das für die Redwendungen](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mit%20spitzer%20Zunge%2Cmit%20scharfer%20Zunge&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmit%20spitzer%20Zunge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmit%20scharfer%20Zunge%3B%2Cc0)).

Ich dachte, ich hätte eine stehende Wendung durcheinander gebracht, und zwar „scharf“ verwandt, obwohl es eigentlich „spitz“ heißt.

Nun denke ich, dass beide gleichwertig sind und es lediglich einen leichten Unterschied gibt, nämlich „scharf“ für den harten Affront und „spitz“ für die intelligente Polemik.

War die Verwirrung gerechtfertigt? Ist die Annahme korrekt? Gibt es da andere Nuancen zwischen?

Comment: Ich würde auch unterscheiden zwischen "eine scharfe Zunge haben" (gibt es m.E.) und "mit scharfer Zunge sprechen" (gibt es m.E. nicht). Dann wäre eine mögliche Erklärung, dass "mit spitzer Zunge sprechen" ein feste Redewendung ist, und ansonsten beides existiert.

Comment: Ich kann bestätigen, dass beides existiert - Einen tatsächlichen Unterschied zwischen den Ausdrücken kann ich allerdings nicht finden - Auch nicht den "kleinen", den du annimmst..

Answer (score 2):

Der [Redensarten-Index](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=zunge%20haben&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) kennt beide Versionen.

> eine scharfe Zunge haben: angriffslustig / widerspruchsvoll reden
>   eine spitze Zunge haben: spöttische / polemische / scharfe / kritische / boshafte Bemerkungen machen

Was auffällt, ist, dass beide Definition — trotz der Verwendung völlig verschiedener Wörter — sehr ähnlich sind. Beide beschreiben im Wesentlichen Kritik oder Opposition, teils sogar in sehr unsachlicher Form (spöttich, polemisch).

Sowohl *spitz-* als auch *scharfzüngig* beschreibt die gleiche Aussage, und zwar das eine provokante Wortwahl vorliegt, womit Streit ersucht wird oder im Falle von Satire eben Personen oder Ereignisse bloß gestellt werden sollen.